# Is it possible to guess an AES key from a series of messages encrypted with that key?

Tags: cryptography

I was wondering if it is practically achievable to guess an AES key from a large number of short messages encrypted with that key, **the attacker knowing the exact content of every message**.
Suppose the messages are very short (one block), and quite many (about 100.000).

If such a cryptographic mechanism is weak, how can it be enforced (sticking with AES)? Maybe a mechanism of salting implemented with, suppose, 10 different algorithm variants and the no. of the variant written into every message?

Thank you in advance for your opinions.

Comment: How many bits is the key expected to be?

Comment: suppose 128 bits

Comment: Salt sounds like a good idea. But varying the algorithm doesn't -- the result can only be as strong as the weakest variant.

Comment: Thanks TonyK. But, sticking to the original question, are there studies that investigate the achievability of finding the key knowing both the original and the encrypted message?

Comment: This is called a "known plaintext attack"; those terms should help you research the subject.  I don't know of any such vulnerabilities in AES, but I am not an expert.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me the good way to search for it. I was searching for "attacker knowing the original message" with little luck. Citing from wikipedia. "Modern ciphers such as Advanced Encryption Standard are not currently susceptible to known-plaintext attacks." I should investigate further, but, by now, I'm satisfied. Please post your comment as an answer soon.

Comment: @Nate: Could you post your comment (and the research result from gd1) as an answer, so gd1 can accept it? I'll vote it up, even :-)

Comment: @J.M.: The key for AES is 128, 192, or 256 bits.  This is in the spec.  AES was adapted from Rijndael, which can have a wider range of keys (and block sizes), but AES restricts parameters as part of the standard.

Comment: Yeah, @Fixee, tweaking with archive files and securing routers made me know more or less remember the number of bits supported for a key; I was (obliquely I guess) having the OP clarify.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not possible to recover an AES key from even a very large number of known plaintext-ciphertext pairs.  In fact, this is one requirement of defining a "strong block cipher".

To be more precise, "There is no **publicly-known** way to extract the key with **non-trivial** probability, given any number of plaintext-ciphertext pairs, in a **practical** amount of time using a **practical** amount of computing resources."

In fact, in order to be considered "good", AES must defend against even stronger attacks than the one you mention.  For example, even if you get to **choose** the plaintexts and you are then given the ciphertexts under some hidden key, you still should not be able to recover the key (this is called a "chosen plaintext attack").

Even if you get to choose plaintexts (and are given the corresponding ciphertexts), and can choose ciphertexts (and are given the corresponding plaintexts), you should still not be able to recover the key.  This is called a "chosen ciphertext attack".

The "gold standard" for block ciphers, however, is none of these.  It's an even more demanding test called "indistinguishability" and it can be stated several ways.  I'll informally give the one usually called IND-CPA.

> Suppose there are two black boxes that look externally the same (both take 128 bits in and output 128 bits out), but internally one is AES under a randomly-chosen (but hidden) key.  The other maps its 128-bit input to a random 128-bit output, but is careful to never map two different inputs to the same output (ie, it's an invertible function, but that's the only restriction).
>
> With this setup in place, consider an attacker (aka an "adversary") that is allowed to query either box with 128-bit strings of her choice.  For each query, she receives a 128-bit response which is either the AES-encryption or a random string.
>
> In order for AES to be considered a "strong" block cipher, no adversary that runs in "reasonable" time using "reasonable" resources should be able to tell which black-box is which with better than a .5+$\epsilon$ probability, where $\epsilon$ is a "small" positive number.

Notice that the goal is **not** key-recovery here: though recovering the key would certainly suffice, the adversary has a much easier goal here.  She needs to simply tell which box is which and she wins.

It is **believed** that AES enjoys IND-CPA, but there is no proof of this.  In fact, there is likely to never be a proof.  So we **assume** it to be true, much as we assume factoring the product of two large primes is intractible.  The good news is that, after these unsettling assumptions around the cryptographic primitives, everything built upon them (modes of operation, MAC schemes, signatures, SSL, SSH, voting, crypto-cash, etc) can be **proven** secure under the assumption that the primitives are secure.

Answer (score 6):

Reposting comment as an answer by popular demand.

This is called a "known plaintext attack"; those terms should help you research the subject. I don't know of any such vulnerabilities in AES, but I am not an expert.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I'll bite: There is no known attack that will recover an AES key from any number of known-plaintext messages in a feasible amount of time. The only reason that salting the messages is a good idea is that it hides repetitions -- but if the attacker already knows the plaintexts, hiding repetitions is futile. HTH.